# Qt paintEvent() unnormally triggered

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, paintevent

I'm a Qt beginner.

So I have my MainWindow with a `QSlider` and a `QPixmap`. I redefined the `paintEvent( QPaintEvent* event )` and

```
connect( slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(centerChange(int)) );
```

with a slot:

```
void MainWindow::centerChange(int value)
{
    center = value;
    update();
}
```

So I wanted repainte the Pixmap only if the slider's value is changed. But I notice that everytime when I make a mouse-in or a mouse-out to the slider, the repaint is triggered. Why is this happenning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paint event may be triggered at any time by the underlying Qt drawing system. You should not assume that paint event can be triggered only by you. You need to change the logic in your app.

Comment: Ok. But if I want to limit the repaint to get better perfomance. Isn't it necessary? Or people just don't do that?

Comment: _But if I want to limit the repaint_


Don't do that, the Qt drawing system is rather good (but not ideal of course). On linux you could try "raster" graphics engine, it is much faster than native.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation [says](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#paintEvent):

> A paint event is a request to repaint all or part of a widget. It can happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> - repaint() or update() was invoked,
> - the widget was obscured and has now been uncovered, or
> - **many other reasons.**

(emphasis mine). Specifically, the underlying OS could trigger a repaint event whenever it feels like.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, don't reimplement `paintEvent` then. Just do your `QPixmap` updating when the slider value changed.